# "Substituto" ideal para o placeholder

Tags: html, input, placeholder

Estou na fase final de um projeto! E agora estou fazendo as analises como testes de desempenho e erros na estruturação! Um dos erros encontrados é o `placeholder` dos inputs e textarea. O que posso usar no lugar do placeholder e que de preferencia nao de erro na hora da validação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria esse erro de validação? É realmente necessário a retirada da propriedade? É o mais adequado para o seu objetivo proposto, semanticamente falando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude seu documento para o HTML5, bastando alterar o [*doctype*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype) no inicio do arquivo para `<!doctype html>`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <!-- head -->
  <body>
     <input type='text' name='foo' placeholder='foo'>
  </body>
</html>
```

Se isto não for possível no seu projeto, pode então optar por utilizar Javascript para criar o mesmo efeito do atributo *placeholder*:

```html
<input type='text' value='foo'
       onfocus="if (this.value === 'foo') {this.value = '';}"
       onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'foo';}">
```

A segunda opção dá um pouco mais de trabalho, não é simplesmente verificar se o valor do campo é "foo" (que foi apenas um exemplo). Nesse caso, utilizar um *plugin* que faça esse tratamento pode ser a melhor solução, por exemplo o [Placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/).